# How to increase the dialog's height in Vuetify framework?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

We use Vuetify component framework in our Vue.js based app. There is a dialog with some built-in components on it. As you can see on the screenshot below two textareas with red rectangles display some information. The issue is I don't need the vertical scroll bars. I need more space inside textareas to fully display the information. In other words, I just need to increase the height of dialog itself in order to increase the height of components including textareas. The dialog looks as following:

[image]

The code looks as following:

```
<template>
  <wrapper>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">Заявка ({{ editedItem.id }})</span>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          <v-container grid-list-md>
            <v-layout wrap>
              <v-flex>
                <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.status" label="Статус"></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.comment" label="Комментарий"></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-textarea :value="fullName(editedItem.user)" label="Клиент" rows="2" disabled></v-textarea>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-textarea :value="unitName(editedItem.search_by)" label="Студия" rows="2" disabled></v-textarea>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-textarea v-if="editedItem.services" :value="studio(editedItem.services)" label="Услуги" rows="2" disabled></v-textarea>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-textarea v-if="editedItem.periods" :value="desiredTime(editedItem.periods)" label="Желаемое время" rows="2" disabled></v-textarea>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-text-field :value="formatDateWithoutHours(editedItem.date)" label="Желаемая дата" disabled></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex>
                <v-text-field :value="formatDate(editedItem.created_at)" label="Дата создания" disabled></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="save">Save</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

I've tried to change several height values, but nothing helps.

Comment: Try auto-grow on v-textarea https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textareas/#auto-grow

Comment: Please, write your answer as regular one and I'll check it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-dialog` component actually grows based on content.

You should try to add `auto-grow` prop to `v-textarea` to make textarea automatically increase in size when the contained text exceeds its size.

[vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textareas/#auto-grow](http://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textareas/#auto-grow)